# Express.js: Users can't log in using

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, ejs, helmet.js

I'm using passport.js and passport-local-mongoose. When trying to log in nothing happens, no error messages either. However, when registering everything is fine, the new user gets added to the database.

I implemented some security headers using helmet.js as well.

```
app.use(
  helmet.hsts({
    maxAge: 63072000,
    preload: true,
  })
);


app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
  directives: {
    connectSrc: ["'self'", 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'],
    defaultSrc: ["'self'", 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'],
    fontSrc: ["'self'"],
    imgSrc: ["'self'", 'data:'],
    scriptSrc: ["'self'", 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'],
    styleSrc: ["'self'",'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'],
    frameSrc: ["'self'", 'https://www.instagram.com/', 'https://www.facebook.com/']
  },


  reportOnly: false,

}));

app.use(
  helmet.referrerPolicy({
    policy: ["strict-origin-when-cross-origin"]
  })
);

app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
app.use(helmet.noSniff());
app.use(
  helmet.frameguard({
    action: "deny",
  })
);





app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
  resave: true,
  httpOnly: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie:{
    secure: true
  }
}));



app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());





passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

I tried to log in with all of the headers disabled, didn't seem to work.

post route for login:

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res){
  User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, foundUser){
    if(foundUser){
      const user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
      });
      passport.authenticate("local", function(err, user){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        else{
          if(user){
            req.login(user, function(err){
              res.redirect("/favourite");
            });
          } else{
            res.redirect("/login");
          }
        }
      })(req, res);
    } else{
      res.redirect("/login")
    }
  });
});
```

login.ejs

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="my-3 btn btn-dark">Log In</button>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add some `console.log()` statements to check which step is failing? For me this usually helps to identify where the code stops working as expected and also to check if the data is as expected.

I see you are using `passport.use(User.createStrategy())`, this requires the `passport-local-mongoose` plugin. Did you load that plugin in the User Mongoose schema?

PS. I have made a single-file example some time ago for logging in with Passport, maybe it can help you. It is not using Mongoose though, but the native MongoDB driver (https://github.com/allardvanderouw/express-api-passport-local-mongo-session-example/blob/master/server.js).

Comment: Thank you, so I found that issue was because of the setting the cookie secure option to true. Though I have no idea why.